# Настройка PHP + APC

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!! У меня проблема. Я установил на свой сервер PHP и APC PHPINFO. И хотел сделать прогресс-бар загрузки файлов (собственно для этого APC и нужна), а в результате во всех тестовых примерах мне вместо инфы о состоянии файлов выдается пустая строка (false).

Настраивал в PHP.ini следующее:

```
 [APC]
 extension=apc.so
 apc.rfc1867=on
 apc.rfc1867_freq = 10k
```

Не помогло

```
<?php
apc_store("test","12345");
echo(apc_fetch("test"));
?>
```

Работает исправно, выдает 12345, из чего делаю вывод, что APC установил и настроил корректно. Помогите, кто сталкивался, плз!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, Flash уже не есть правильно для прогресса загрузки, как и Java-апплет на стороне клиента. Рекоммендую поставить подходящее Вам PECL-расширение для этого, плюс - имейте в виду - прокси посередине между клиентом и сервером могут давать подобную проблему. Как и - в частности - Nginx на стороне сервера. Пишите уточнение вопроса и задачи - помогу с удовольствием.

Answer (score 0):

А с чего вы взяли что для прогресса загрузки файлов нужно апц ?  Видимо его требует какая-то специфическая библиотека ? Если так ? Почему вы не указали название этой библиотеки ?

Сейчас прогресс загрузки делается либо через ajax, либо (кросплатформенно через flash).